# Organizing multiple AJAX/PHP snippets

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have several blocks of code that I make ajax calls too from various jquery events. I was wondering if there were any negatives for keeping those small blocks of code in one large file or if it would be better to keep them separated. I only have a couple now, but it could grow to maybe a dozen.

Answer (score 0):

Depends entirely on how your application is structured. In general, it is better to break up your application so that each individual component is in a different file. It is much more clean and organized this way. Although, if you have a small application, sometimes it's not worth doing.

I usually have multiple JS files page. One contains the code that is relevant to the whole site, and is included on all pages. A second file contains the code that is relevant to the type of page. A third file contains the code that is relevant only to that page. Using scoping like this helps you keeps only code that is needed on the page. As the application gets more complex, then I may further break apart each large file into smaller files to keep everything organized.

Comment: That's sorta what I was thinking, but at the same time some of these ajax calls are to simple php queries that are maybe only 10 lines of code long. Not sure if that matters or not. I guess I'm just trying to suss out any advantages of keeping them in one file vs. multiple files.

Comment: If you post your code in the question I can give you a more accurate opinion.